# Jquery load more posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to add at the bottom of my jquery mobile page a 'Load More' link so when users click on it, it loads more blog posts from my wordpress site using json api.

This is my js code:

```
function listPosts(data) {
  var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
  $.each(data.posts,function(key,val) {
    output += '<li>';
output += '<a href="#bpost" onclick="displayPost(' + val.id + ')">';
output += '<h3>' + val.title + '</h3>';
    output += '<div class="postexcerpt">' + excerpt + '</div>';
output += '</a>';
output += '</li>';
  }); // go through each post
  output+='</ul>';
  $('#postlist').html(output);
} // lists all the posts
```

My html code:

```
<!-- Page: blog -->
  <div id="blog" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" class="sys_header" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_header" >
<h1>Sysads Posts</h1></div><!-- header --> 
<div data-theme="c" data-role="content" id="postlist"> </div><!-- content -->
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_footer" >
    <div data-role="navbar" >
<ul>
<li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Disclaimer</a></li>
</ul></div><!-- navbar --> 
</div><!-- footer --> 
</div><!-- page -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not different to the paged search results only that the extra fetches are displayed after the current entries. So what you need to do:
In Javascript
On your 'Load More' prompt you need to send the 'next page number' to the server.

On the server:
convert the 'page number' to a starting record number (pgNbr*10)
then send the sql statement information on where to start looking for data and the number of records to return i.e.

```
SELECT .....
LIMIT $pgNbr, 10
```

Comment: Sorry I am newbie to jquery so not sure where the SQL like select should be included. Is it not possible to have like a text link in html or javascript that when clicked should call a function that would load more posts?

Thanks

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324729/load-wordpress-posts-using-jquery?rq=1